# Python 3 Streams in PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2, qthread

please help me figure out the threads in PySide2!

I can't understand it at all...

I want to make it so that when the window is opened, the processes are executed in parallel and the table is filled in as the functions work. However, where and no matter how I insert QThread, my_signal and QThread.start() - there is very little sense.

Code:

```
import time

class Qthre(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Qthre, self).__init__(parent)
        self.value = 0
    
    def run(self):
        def CkeckFileInBase():
            Base = sqlite3.connect(r"wowlist.db", uri=True)
            Base.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            Cur = Base.cursor()
            s = 'SELECT * FROM files'
            Cur.execute(s)
            records = Cur.fetchall()
            spisok_zla = []
            spisok_zla2 = []
            for row in records:
                c = CkeckHash(row[0], row[1])
                if c:
                    pass
                else:
                    if os.path.exists(row[0]):
                        h1 = DeShifroHash(row[1])
                        newH = HashCal(row[0])
                        spisok_zla.append((row[0], h1, newH))
                    else:
                        spisok_zla2.append((row[0], h1, 'File not found'))
            return spisok_zla
        spisok_zla = CkeckFileInBase()
            
        data = []
        for item in spisok_zla:
            mtime = os.path.getmtime(item[0])
            dataIzm = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(mtime), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
            dataIzm = str(dataIzm.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y'))
            data.append((item[0], str(item[2]), str(item[1]), dataIzm))
        return data 

def MainWindow():
    loader = QUiLoader()
    
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    ...
    def winCheck():
        """окно проверки файлов из базы данных"""
        winCh = loader.load("ui\\check.ui", window)
        
        # Получаем список файлов
        #data = SpisokZlaForTable()
        Qthre1 = Qthre(winCh)
        Qthre1.start()
        data = Qthre1.run()
        print(data)
        
        # заполняем таблицу
        #winCh.tbIzmFiles.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 781, 291))
        #winCh.tbIzmFiles.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 781, 291))
        #winCh.tbIzmFiles.setRowCount(len(data))
        winCh.tbIzmFiles.setColumnCount(4)
        
        winCh.tbIzmFiles.setHorizontalHeaderLabels( # проверь, что не напутал с хешами
                ('Файл:', 'новый Хеш:', 'старый Хеш:', 'Дата изменения:')
            )
        
        row = 0
        for tup in data:
            col = 0
            for item in tup:
                cellinfo = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(item)
                cellinfo.setFlags(
                            QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
                        )
                winCh.tbIzmFiles.setItem(row, col, cellinfo)
                col += 1
    
            row += 1
        winCh.tbIzmFiles.resizeColumnsToContents()
        winCh.tbIzmFiles.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
        winCh.tbIzmFiles.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        
        # Показать окно
        winCh.show()
        
    window.pbCheck.clicked.connect(winCheck)
    ...

    window.show()
    # window.update()
    app.exec_()
    
MainWindow()
```

How and where to use QThread in here? I've already read about it and still can't understand anything

Comment: What processes? What signals? Please add more details to clarify where is the problem.

Comment: That's what I wrote! the winCheck function is started and the program window hangs until data works = SpisokZlaForTable()

Comment: I don't see any attempt to use QThread. Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre] of your attempts.

Comment: Where is the `my_signal` you were talking about? Also, you should *not* call `run()`, it will be executed internally when `start()` is called.